# Working on epub using CSS columns, regarding pagination

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagination, epub

I'm working on epub file formats to be read in the browser. **Using CSS columns** I can divide the content into several columns (several pages) based on the window height. **Using Next/Previous button, I'll do translateX**.

My question is regarding pagination. How can I determine:

- the total number of columns present in the browser for a particular ebook which I will use it as total number of pages.
- Current column visible in the viewport, which I will use it as current page location.

If CSS columns are not good for this case, You could suggest me any better approach to this.

**EDIT: I'm rendering epubs as a reflowable content (dynamic pagination).**

Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but I think you're going to run into a brick wall with these CSS columns. I don't know how to get the total number of columns, or the current visible column. You could take a look at Readium, or the EPUB reading support in the latest version of Edge, to see how they do it, but I think the basic idea is to render the entire book in one vertical area, and then adjust which part of that you show on the page.

Comment: I don't know about Edge browser, but for Readium.. from what I've seen, they don't have pagination or percentage read feature in their app :)

Comment: Readium absolutely has pagination.

Comment: Check here https://github.com/readium/readium-js-viewer/issues/319 I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5):

A better approach would be to generate your own columns.

See my [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ryanbriscall/ncxgpxkw/), which uses [lib_columns.js](https://cdn.rawgit.com/dpup/13thparallel.com/master/static/archive/column-script/lib_columns.js), [jquery.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js), and [jquery.easyPaginate.js](http://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/js/jquery.easyPaginate.js).

For more information on easyPaginate.js, see [website](http://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/).

For more information on lib_columns.js, see [website](http://13thparallel.com/archive/column-script/).

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
html, body { overflow: hidden; height: 100%; }

/* Hide the source containers, by visual only. */
#divSizer, #content {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}

/* E-book */
.ebook-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #CCC;
}
#ebook {
    /*width: 300px; (generated by JavaScript) */
    /*height: 500px; (generated by JavaScript) */
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 4px dashed red;
    /*overflow: auto; (Provide scrollbar) */
}

/* Pagination Menu */
.ebook-container .easyPaginateNav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2em;
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center;
}
.ebook-container .easyPaginateNav a { padding: 5px; }
.ebook-container .easyPaginateNav a.current { font-weight: bold; }

/* Show only the current page in pagination, hide the rest. */
.ebook-container .easyPaginateNav a.page         { display: none; }
.ebook-container .easyPaginateNav a.page.current { display: inline; }

/* Text-size Menu */
.ebook-container .textSizeNav {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -70px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<body style="font-size: 1.4em;">
    <div id="divSizer"></div>

    <div id="content">
        <h2>7.1 Introduction to media types</h2>

        <p>One of the most important features of style sheets is that they
        specify how a document is to be presented on different media: on the
        screen, on paper, with a speech synthesizer, with a braille device,
        etc.</p>

        <h3>Features of Style Sheets</h3>

        <p>Certain CSS properties are only designed for certain media (e.g.,
        the 'cue-before' property for aural user agents).
        On occasion, however, style sheets for different
        media types may share a property, but require different values for
        that property. For example, the 'font-size' property is useful both
        for screen and print media. However, the two media are different
        enough to require different values for the common property; a document
        will typically need a larger font on a computer screen than on paper.
        Experience also shows that sans-serif fonts are easier to read on
        screen, while fonts with serifs are easier to read on paper.  For
        these reasons, it is necessary to express that a style sheet -- or a
        section of a style sheet -- applies to certain media types.</p>

        <h4>Features of Style Sheets</h4>

        <p>One of the most important features of style sheets is that they
        specify how a document is to be presented on different media: on the
        screen, on paper, with a speech synthesizer, with a braille device,
        etc.</p>

        <p>Experience also shows that sans-serif fonts are easier to read on
        screen, while fonts with serifs are easier to read on paper.  For
        these reasons, it is necessary to express that a style sheet -- or a
        section of a style sheet -- applies to certain media types.</p>

        <h4>Document to be Presented</h4>

        <p>Experience also shows that sans-serif fonts are easier to read on
        screen, while fonts with serifs are easier to read on paper.  However,
        the two media are different enough to require different values for the
        common property</p>

        <p>Certain CSS properties are only designed for certain media (e.g.,
        the 'cue-before' property for aural user agents).
        On occasion, however, style sheets for different.</p>

        <h4>Features of Style Sheets</h4>

        <p>One of the most important features of style sheets is that they
        specify how a document is to be presented on different media: on the
        screen, on paper, with a speech synthesizer, with a braille device,
        etc.</p>

        <p>Experience also shows that sans-serif fonts are easier to read on
        screen, while fonts with serifs are easier to read on paper.  For
        these reasons, it is necessary to express that a style sheet -- or a
        section of a style sheet -- applies to certain media types.</p>

        <h4>Document to be Presented</h4>

        <p>Experience also shows that sans-serif fonts are easier to read on
        screen, while fonts with serifs are easier to read on paper.  However,
        the two media are different enough to require different values for the
        common property</p>

        <p>Certain CSS properties are only designed for certain media (e.g.,
        the 'cue-before' property for aural user agents).
        On occasion, however, style sheets for different.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="ebook-container">
        <div id="ebook"></div>

        <div class="textSizeNav">
            <button id="plustext" class="btn btn-circle" onclick="resizeText(1); $(window).resize();">A<sup><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></sup></button>
            <button id="minustext" class="btn btn-circle" onclick="resizeText(-1); $(window).resize();"><small>A</small><sup><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span></sup></button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dpup/13thparallel.com/master/static/archive/column-script/lib_columns.j"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://st3ph.github.io/jquery.easyPaginate/js/jquery.easyPaginate.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.easyPaginate.func.my_paginate.js"></script>
    <script src="my_app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT** - jquery.easyPaginate.func.my_paginate.js

```
<!-- jquery.easyPaginate.func.my_paginate.js -->
<script>
function my_paginate(book_selector, content_selector, params)
{
    // Override default options.
    params = $.extend({
        pageWidth:       300,
        pageHeight:      500,
        earlyCutOff:     0,
        paginateElement: 'div',
        elementsPerPage: 1,
        effect:          'default', // Choose: 'fade', 'slide', or 'climb'
        prevButtonText: '<',
        firstButtonText: '<<',
        nextButtonText: '>',
        lastButtonText: '>>'
    }, params);

    // If content container is empty, then break.
    var content = $(content_selector);
    if (content.length == 0) return;

    // Reset easyPaginate:
    // - Check if pagination already exists.
    // - Remove pagination, and clear the e-book container.
    var sel = '.easyPaginateNav';
    var pagination = $(book_selector).parent().children(sel);
    if (pagination.length > 0) {
        pagination.first().remove();
        $(book_selector).html('');
    }

    // Generate pages. (splits the content)
    // Note: All pages will have:
    // - class="page"
    // - data-page-num="*"
    var cols = Columns.splitText(
        content.html(),
        params.pageWidth,
        (params.pageHeight - params.earlyCutOff) // Sometimes too long.
    );
    for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i ++)
    {
        $(book_selector).append(
            '<' + params.paginateElement +
            ' class="page"' +
            ' data-page-num="' + (i + 1) + '"' +
            '>' +
            cols[i] +
            '</' + params.paginateElement + '>'
        );
    }

    // Prepare the e-book container.
    var book = $(book_selector);
    book.css('width', params.pageWidth + 'px');
    book.css('height', params.pageHeight + 'px');

    // Generate/render E-book.
    book.easyPaginate({
        paginateElement: params.paginateElement,
        elementsPerPage: params.elementsPerPage,
        effect: params.effect,
        prevButtonText: params.prevButtonText,
        firstButtonText: params.firstButtonText,
        nextButtonText: params.nextButtonText,
        lastButtonText: params.lastButtonText
    });
}
</script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT** - my_app.js

```
<!-- my_app.js -->
<script>
// When document is ready.
$(function() {
    // When the screen size/dimensions changes:
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        // Current screen size.
        var width = $(window).width() - 150; // 150px gutter.
        var height = $(window).height() - 125; // 125px gutter.

        // Render e-book.
        my_paginate('#ebook', '#content', {
            pageWidth: width,
            pageHeight: height,
            prevButtonText: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
            firstButtonText: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
            nextButtonText: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
            lastButtonText: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward" aria-hidden="true"></span>',
            earlyCutOff: 50
        });
    }).resize(); // Force trigger a resize event.
});
</script>
```

**JAVASCRIPT** - extra

```
<script>
function resizeText(multiplier) {
    if (document.body.style.fontSize == "") {
        document.body.style.fontSize = "1.0em";
    }
    document.body.style.fontSize = parseFloat(document.body.style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + "em";
}
</script>
```

**Comments**

Using CSS Columns (via the "columns:" property) would be difficult because those columns are generated by CSS, not HTML.

With HTML (markup), we then have our columns in the DOM and therefore can better interact with and manipulate them.

You then use JavaScript libraries such as [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to interact with and manipulate your columns.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm particularly looking for the answer that has *manipulation example* to get the page numbers. Either using html tables or css flexbox.

Comment: For educational purpose, that answer would be useful to be here in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Flexbox is not going to help, since it has no way to flow content from one box into another.

Comment: @rnk I've provided a demo now.

Comment: @RyanBriscall Thank you very much! I checked the demo and it looks great. I need some time to read the code. I'll get back once I did that.

Comment: @RyanBriscall I'm marking this answer as incorrect. lib_columns.js doesn't work for images. As I'm talking about epubs images and other media types are very important.